# Телеграм бот отвечает не тому пользователю Python Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, бот, чат

Когда бота использует один человек, всё работает, но если зайти в него с другого аккаунта и начать взаимодействовать, бот начинает отвечать первому пользователю, а не тому, кто с ним взамодействует. Не знаю, в чём причина, помогите, пожалуйста. Проблемы возникают с самого начала, поэтому прикрепляю его.

```
import telebot
import random
import string
from telebot import types
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Приветствуем вас, {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}, в боте по продаже внутриигровых предметов для онлайн игр <b>EverShop</b>! В наличии есть читы для <b><u>CS2, Dota 2, Standoff 2, Roblox</u></b>.',parse_mode='html')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('CS2', callback_data='cs2'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Dota 2', callback_data='dota2'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Standoff 2', callback_data='standoff2'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Roblox', callback_data='roblox'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Укажите, какой проект вас интересует.',parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
    def callback_message(callback):
        if callback.data == 'cs2':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('тото', callback_data='1'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('тото', callback_data='1'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('тото', callback_data='1'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('тото', callback_data='2'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='nazad'))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, выберите, какой товар вас интересует.', reply_markup=markup)
        elif callback.data == 'dota2':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('тото', callback_data='3'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='nazad'))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, выберите, какой товар вас интересует.', reply_markup=markup)
        elif callback.data == 'standoff2':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('ПК', callback_data='pohui'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Смартфон', callback_data='pohui'))
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='nazad'))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, выберите свою платформу.', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Бота запускаю на компьютере, никуда не выгружал

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Я в функции callback использовал обработчик message, а не callback.message.